# Extract CLOB with 300,000 characters from Oracle Table to CSV

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob, regexp-replace

Need to extract a Oracle CLOB from table to CSV delimited with pipe, but encountered the 32700 character limit. The value has more than 300,000 characters. Also, how can we replace the new line with spaces. I tried regexp_replace but it has again 32700 limit..

Any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Use DBMS_LOB package and create an API to unload CLOB into CSV.

Comment: DBMS_LOB doc: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_lob.htm#TTPLP66624

Comment: if you can give the code snippet which you tried, we may provide better assistance. we have done similar thing of this sort where we did BLOB --> B64/CLOB --> SPOOL Via SQL*PLUS

Comment: Is this a one-off exercise for a specific CLOB? Or something you'll want to do often? Do you need something which can be called by a client program or something which is run from SQL*Plus or whatever tool you use? Where do you want the file written? DB server file system or your local desktop? Also, *"how can we replace the new line with spaces"*? Eh? Your CLOB contains newline characters but you want a CSV file with just one line of values?

Answer (score 0):

> how can we replace the new line with spaces. I tried `regexp_replace` but it has again 32700 limit.

Just use the [`REPLACE` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REPLACE.html#GUID-1A79BDDF-2D3B-4AD4-98E7-985B2E59DA6B) as, when the input is a `CLOB` then the output is a `CLOB`:

> `REPLACE` returns `char` with every occurrence of `search_string` replaced with `replacement_string`. If `replacement_string` is omitted or null, then all occurrences of `search_string` are removed. If `search_string` is null, then `char` is returned.
>
> Both `search_string` and `replacement_string`, as well as `char`, can be any of the datatypes `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`, `CLOB`, or `NCLOB`. The string returned is in the same character set as `char`. The function returns `VARCHAR2` if the first argument is not a LOB and returns `CLOB` if the first argument is a LOB.

For the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value CLOB );

DECLARE
  p_value CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 20 LOOP
    p_value := p_value || LPAD( '123456789' || CHR(10), 4000, '123456789|' );
  END LOOP;
  
  INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( p_value );
END;
/
```

Then the query:

```sql
SELECT LENGTH( REPLACE( value, CHR(10), ' ' ) ) AS len,
       REPLACE( value, CHR(10), ' ' ) AS value
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> ```
> LEN   VALUE
> 40000 123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789 123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|12345<snip...>56789|123456789 123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789
> ```

After that, just extract the CLOB in the normal manner for the application you are using to access the database.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c7b58db1a8caf6ed24f5db7dbae5504)*